# Flutter Getx theme change textColor not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I want to use light mode and dark mode in my application. I decided to use getx themes for this.  When I switch to dark mode, scaffold color and app bar color change, but text color doesn't change.
Note: Colors change when I hot reload

I'm writing the code to switch to dark mode below

```
Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark);
```

The theme I am using is in the code below

```
  getDarkTheme(context) => ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xff181A20),
      appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff181A20),
          elevation: 0,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white)),
      textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
          displayColor: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: GoogleFonts.urbanist().fontFamily),
      primaryColor: const Color(0xff181A20));
```

Note: I was using the code below to change the text color theme, but it doesn't change instantly either.

```
textTheme: TextTheme(
   displayMedium: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontFamily: GoogleFonts.urbanist().fontFamily)),
```

The text widget I use is below;

```
Text(
    text,
    style: Theme.of(Get.context!).textTheme.displayLarge!.copyWith(
        fontSize: fontSize,
        fontWeight: fontWeight),
    textAlign: isCenter ? TextAlign.center : TextAlign.start,
  );
```

This is how i use the theme;

```
GetMaterialApp(
initialRoute: AppPages.initialRoute,
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
theme: Themes().getLightTheme(context),
darkTheme: Themes().getDarkTheme(context),
themeMode: ThemeService().getThemeMode(),
getPages: AppPages.routes);
```

When I want to change the theme in my application, I want the text color to change instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a loading screen and this is how I solved the error for now